# Android Gradle Lint - How to fail build when Kotlin's 'unused' warning is present?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, lint

I want my build to fail if the `Unused Symbol` Kotlin Lint error is present. More specifically, I want the build to fail if I have a class that has been declared but not used.

I'm currently using the following Gradle configuration to fail the build when there are unused resources:

```
lintOptions {
    ...
    fatal("UnusedResources")
}
```

But I can't find anything similar for `Unused Symbol`.